# RegionPlot strange problem

Tags: plotting

I have strange problem with Wolfram *Mathematica*'s function `RegionPlot`

```
RegionPlot[x - y == 0, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
```

the result is:

[image]

But when I try

```
RegionPlot[x - y == 1, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Do you know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Documentation states that "RegionPlot will only visualize two-dimensional regions: ".  So, the question is, why did the first plot show a line?

Comment: I'm doing exercise in which I need to use function RegionPlot to draw a line, but I guess there must be an error in exercise.

Comment: There is not an error in your exercise!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with v10.0 you can use [InfiniteLine](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html)

```
RegionPlot[
 InfiniteLine[{x, x - 1} /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1}}], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 100}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

What do you want

```
ContourPlot[x - y == 1, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

or should it be

```
RegionPlot[x - y < 1, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Addendum for exercise. You have to define a region!

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x - y == 1, {x, y}];
RegionPlot@reg
```

[image]

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x - y == 1 && 0 < x < 100 && 0 < y < 100, {x, y}];
RegionPlot@reg
```

[image]

RegionPlot will only visualize two-dimensional regions. See the documentation "Possible Issues".

Comment: I'm doing exercise in which I need to use function  RegionPlot to draw a line.

Comment: @rewi Why did the first example work? This seems to be a one-dimensional region which violates the **Possible Issues** in the documentation.

Comment: @Jack LaVigne Unfortunately, I also know not all :)

Comment: @JackLaVigne The example in possible issues seems to need modification since the introduction of ImplicitRegions

Answer (score 4):

Correction:

```
RegionPlot[x - y == 1, {x, 0, 100}, {y, -1, 99}]
```

Why does it work? Consider the following example. `RegionPlot` understands `True` statement (put any `a`).

```
With[{a = 50}, 
 RegionPlot[x - y == a, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0 - a, 100 - a}]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I think you have nailed it. Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the sampling pattern used by RegionPlot, it is lucky that it finds the line in your first example.  Consider the output of

```
noisyFunction[x_, y_] := Module[{},
    Sow[{x, y}];
    x - y
];
ListPlot[
  Take[
    Reap[
      RegionPlot[noisyFunction[x, y] == 0, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
    ][[2, 1]],
  {4, -1}]
]
```

The clustering of samples around the line is easily seen.  But RegionPlot is not lucky for your second example.

```
ListPlot[
  Take[
    Reap[
      RegionPlot[noisyFunction[x, y] == 1, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
    ][[2, 1]],
  {4, -1}]
]
```

One should use EvaluationMonitor if one is going to be serious about inspecting the evaluation set of a function fed to a plot or numerical search.